# Loop through numbered variabled in DS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that consists of variables named month0-month120 and for each record I am trying to check if these variables equal a particular value. I am having a bit of trouble trying to do this dynamically rather than writing 120 lines of code. How would be the proper way to accomplish this? I am also having trouble formulating how to word the question which is also hindering me when searching online.

Edit: So basically I have this time series of values from the last 5 years represented in month0-120. I am trying to see how many '.' values are present within this array for each record. An example of input is as such

```
data testing;
    set blah;

    len = 0;

    do i = 0 to 120;
        if month[i] = . then len+1;
    end;


run;
```

Comment: Are you searching for a particular value in at least one of the variables?  For example the value 10?  `whichn(10, of month0-month120)`

Comment: Post an example input dataset (just 2 or 3 observations and 2 or 3 MONTHnn variables) and what result you are trying to get from that example data.

Comment: Are you familiar with Arrays in SAS? https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-arrays/

Comment: @Tom I have updated the question to illustrate what I am trying to do. Reeza yes, but whenever I utilize array months(*) month0-month120 I get array subscript out of range errors no matter if I call index 0 or 100

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of missing values use NMISS().

```
data testing;
  set blah;
  len = nmiss(of month0-month120);
run;
```

Note CMISS() will also work since CMISS() works with both numeric and character variables.

For more general solution for referencing a set of variables use an ARRAY.

```
data testing;
  set blah;
  array months month0-month120;
  do index=1 to dim(months);
    * do something with MONTHS[index] ;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code you posted, you would need to explicitly declare your array and it's easier if you specify the index from 0 to 120. Otherwise, SAS would index it from 1 to 121 essentially.

```
data testing;
    set blah;

    array months(0:120) month0-month120;
    len = 0;

    do i = 0 to 120;
        if month[i] = . then len+1;
    end;


run;
```